# How to add new object to spawning method after 50 points in sprite-kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I have 6 different kinds of enemys in my game and I want to start spawning a random one till I have 50 points and then add a new random one. I want to do this till all enemys are in play. In this moment all enemys are in play from the beginning.

I have an arc4random switch statement that is called wenn my moving ground is in a certain position. I read that a NSMutableArray could be a solution but it only can have objects inside.

Here is the code I have:

```
// The method that is called to add an random enemy:
-(void)addRandomEnemy {

switch (arc4random() % 12) {
    case 0:
        [self addEnemy1];
        break;
    case 1:
        [self addEnemy2];
        break;
    case 2:
        [self addEnemy3];
        break;
    case 3:
        [self addEnemy4];
        break;
    case 4:
        [self addEnemy5];
        break;
    case 5:
        [self addEnemy6];
        break;
    }
}

// Inside the update method:
if (ground.position.x < 333 && ground.position.x > 328) {

        [self addRandomEnemy];
    }
if (ground.position.x < 666 && ground.position.x > 661) {

        [self addRandomEnemy];
    }
```

My question is how can I add a new kind of enemys to a spawning cycle after a specific amount of points for example ?

Thanks guys ! (code in objective-c please)

EDIT UPDATE code:

```
-(void)addRandomEnemy:(int)number {

// Array
NSArray *numberArray = @[@0, @1, @2, @3, @4 ,@5, @6]; 
NSMutableArray *numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:numberArray];

// shuffle
NSUInteger count = [numbers count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {

    int nElements = count - i;
    int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
    [numbers exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}

// Here I can't replace the case 0 with numbers[0]
switch (arc4random() % number) {
case 0:
    [self addEnemy1];
    break;
case 1:
    [self addEnemy2];
    break;
case 2:
    [self addEnemy3];
    break;
case 3:
    [self addEnemy4];
    break;
case 4:
    [self addEnemy5];
    break;
case 5:
    [self addEnemy6];
    break;
   }
}
```

It now says: "Expression is not an Integer constant expression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//This 2 arrays you should initialize like properties, not in the update method, because otherwise result array will be always with 1 random element 
NSMutableArray *numberArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5]];
NSMutableArray *resultArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:6];

NSNumber *randomType = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:(arc4random() % number)];

        if ([numberArray containsObject:randomType]) {
            [numberArray removeObject:randomType];
            if (![resultArr containsObject:randomType]) {
                [resultArr addObject:randomType];
            }
        }

        NSNumber *enemyTypeIndex = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:arc4random() % [resultArr count]];
       [self addSomeEnemy:[resultArr objectAtIndex:[enemyTypeIndex integerValue]]];
```

And thats your adSomeEnemy method(uncomment methods call):

```
- (void)addSomeEnemy:(NSNumber *)enemy {

    switch ([enemy integerValue]) {

        case 0:
            //[self addEnemy1];
            break;
        case 1:
           // [self addEnemy2];
            break;
        case 2:
            //[self addEnemy3];
            break;
        case 3:
           // [self addEnemy4];
            break;
        case 4:
           // [self addEnemy5];
            break;
        case 5:
           // [self addEnemy6];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Only what you should do now - make 2 first arrays as properties, initialize them where you want(but before the first update call), for example in initWithSize method, and replace "numberArray"/"resultArr" with "self.numberArray"/"self.resultArr"

Comment: Thats not what I am looking for. I already have an score and time. The timing is already how I want it. My problem is that I dont want to have all my enemys from the beginning but slowly adding them to the game

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I am really searching for. In the update method I first check the score and then spawn and everything works fine, but in my addRandomEnemy{} I have 6 different kind of enemys that can be spawned, but I only want to spawn 1 kind the first 50 and after 100 I want to have 2 possible enemys and after 150 I want 3 possible kinds and so on. Don't think my problem is the spawning limit or something like this

Comment: Get it. The easy way to do it, is to replace "switch (arc4random() % 12)" to switch "(arc4random() % NUMBER)", and NUMBER is how much kinds of enemies do you need. You will need to add one parameter to your function "addRandomEnemy" to do that. And if you want to shuffle your enemies, you can just make an array[0,1,2,3,4,5], shuffle it, and replace your "case 0", "case 1" etc, to "case arr[0]", "case arr[1]"...

Comment: Wow you are a genius everything worked. I only have problems now with the "arr[0]" etc. I replaced it with my arrays name but he it says: "use of undeclared indentifer". How can I fix this

Comment: Okay thanks, but i can't see exactly what you mean. Can you update your answer with this alternative ? Only if you have time for it

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your help ! The only thing is that I am not sure where to put the part with "NSNumber *randomType [...] if ([numberArray containsObject:randomType]) [...] NSNumber *enemyTypeIndex [...]". I think in the update method ? I think after this question I got it

Comment: I think you should put it in addRandomEnemy method, because that method you call from the update method: "if (ground.position.x < 333 && ground.position.x > 328) {

        [self addRandomEnemy];
    }"

Comment: You need both the addRandomEnemy and addSomeEnemy methods, if you miss that moment(but ofc you can rename them better)